# How do I add the native WooCommerce authentication to my custom WooCommerce endpoint?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a custom WC API endpoint which I want to protect using WooCommerce authentication, ie:

```
my-site.com/wp-json/wc/v3/custom?consumer_key=ck...&consumer_secret=cs...
```

How would I achieve this? I know about JWT authentication but that's not acceptible in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'wc_custom_endpoint');
function wc_custom_endpoint(){
  register_rest_route('wc/v3', 'custom', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'return_value',
    'permission_callback' => function($request){      
      return is_user_logged_in();
    }
  ));
}

function return_value(){
    return "this is my custom endpoint!";
}
```

Try this